# Change to empty array if another column is false

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a dataframe that returns an empty array for a nested struct type if another column is false. I created a dummy dataframe to illustrate my problem.

```
import spark.implicits._

val newDf = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("user1","true", Some(8), Some("usd"), Some("tx1")),
  ("user1", "true", Some(9), Some("usd"), Some("tx2")),
  ("user2", "false", None, None, None))).toDF("userId","flag", "amount", "currency", "transactionId")


val amountStruct = struct("amount"
                          ,"currency").alias("amount")

val transactionStruct = struct("transactionId"
                               , "amount").alias("transactions")

val dataStruct = struct("flag","transactions").alias("data")


val finalDf = newDf.
withColumn("amount", amountStruct).
withColumn("transactions", transactionStruct).
select("userId", "flag","transactions").
groupBy("userId", "flag").
agg(collect_list("transactions").alias("transactions")).
withColumn("data", dataStruct).
drop("transactions","flag")
```

This is the output:

```
+------+--------------------+
|userId|                data|
+------+--------------------+
| user2|  [false, [[, [,]]]]|
| user1|[true, [[tx1, [8,...|
+------+--------------------+
```

and schema:

```
root
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- flag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- transactions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- transactionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- amount: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
```

The output I want:

```
+------+--------------------+
|userId|                data|
+------+--------------------+
| user2|  [false, []]       |
| user1|[true, [[tx1, [8,...|
+------+--------------------+
```

I've tried doing this before doing `collect_list` but no luck.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

val emptyArray = typedLit(Array.empty[(String, Array[(Int, String)])])

testDf.withColumn("transactions", when($"flag" === "false", emptyArray).otherwise($"transactions")).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were moments from victory. The approach with `collect_list` is the way to go, it just needs a little nudge.

## TL;DR Solution

```scala
val newDf = spark
  .createDataFrame(
    Seq(
      ("user1",  "true", Some(8), Some("usd"), Some("tx1")),
      ("user1",  "true", Some(9), Some("usd"), Some("tx2")),
      ("user2", "false", None,    None,        None)
    )
  )
  .toDF("userId", "flag", "amount", "currency", "transactionId")

val dataStruct = struct("flag", "transactions")

val finalDf2 = newDf
  .groupBy("userId", "flag")
  .agg(
    collect_list(
      when(
        $"transactionId".isNotNull && $"amount".isNotNull && $"currency".isNotNull,
        struct(
          $"transactionId",
          struct($"amount", $"currency").alias("amount")
        )
      )).alias("transactions"))
  .withColumn("data", dataStruct)
  .drop("transactions", "flag")
```

## Explanation

### SQL Aggregate Function Behavior

First of all, when it comes to behavior Spark follows SQL conventions. All the SQL aggregation functions (and `collect_list` is an aggregate function) ignore NULL on input as if it never was there.

Let's take a look at how does `collect_list` behave:

```scala
Seq(
  ("a", Some(1)),
  ("a", Option.empty[Int]),
  ("a", Some(3)),
  ("b", Some(10)),
  ("b", Some(20)),
  ("b", Option.empty[Int])
)
  .toDF("col1", "col2")
  .groupBy($"col1")
  .agg(collect_list($"col2") as "col2_list")
  .show()
```

And the result is:

```
+----+---------+
|col1|col2_list|
+----+---------+
|   b| [10, 20]|
|   a|   [1, 3]|
+----+---------+
```

### Tracking Down Nullability

It looks like `collect_list` behaves properly. So the reason you are seeing those blanks in your output is that the column that gets passed to the `collect_list` is not nullable.

To prove it let's examine the schema of the DataFrame just before it gets aggregated:

```scala
newDf
  .withColumn("amount", amountStruct)
  .withColumn("transactions", transactionStruct)
  .printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- transactionId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- transactions: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- transactionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
```

Note the `transactions: struct (nullable = false)` part. It proves the suspicion.

If we translate all the nested NULLables to Scala here's what you got:

```scala
case class Row(
    transactions: Transactions,
    // other fields
)

case class Transactions(
    transactionId: Option[String],
    amount: Option[Amount],
)

case class Amount(
    amount: Option[Int],
    currency: Option[String]
)
```

And here's what you want instead:

```scala
case class Row(
    transactions: Option[Transactions], // this is optional now
    // other fields
)

case class Transactions(
    transactionId: String,              // while this is not optional
    amount: Amount,                     // neither is this
)

case class Amount(
    amount: Int,                        // neither is this
    currency: String                    // neither is this
)
```

### Fixing the Nullability

Now the last step is simple. To make the column that is the input to `collect_list` "properly" nullable you have to check the nullability of all the `amount`, `currency` and `transactionId` columns.

The result will be `NOT NULL` if and only if all the input columns are `NOT NULL`.

You can use the same `when` API method to construct the result. The `otherwise` clause if omitted implicitly returns `NULL` which is exactly what you need.